# man page gives "gzip: stdout: Permission denied" error

Tags: manpage

I am using Linux Mint 21 and had to compile some programs from source, so I manually updated `MANPATH` to include their man pages. However when I try to view them, I get the following line at the bottom of the pager [(see screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSxjs.png):

```
gzip: stdout: Permission denied
```

The man page opens without any problem, but I would nevertheless like to fix this issue.

I have verified that the path from which the man page is opening is the path I set in `MANPATH`.

```
$ man --path xdotool
/home/<path-to-files>/xdotool/man/man1/xdotool.1
```

It is also not specific to the above man page, the same issue is in all the man pages I have added locally through setting `MANPATH`.

Comment: `strace -o man-xdotool.strace -s 2048 -f man xdotool` and then read the `man-xdotool.strace` log that generates; that way you'll be able to see which process started gzip, with which arguments, and (importantly!) with stdout connected to which file.

Comment: BTW, you haven't told us your operating system, which means we don't know who made your copy of `man`, and if we want to refer to documentation, means we don't know which vendor's documentation to refer to.

Comment: It's Linux Mint 21, I should have started with that! My bad

Comment: Interestingly, the strace does not have any mention of gzip/gunzip/zip/tar/untar at all!

Comment: Hm. Is there perhaps an alias or shell function overriding man for you? (If so, strace wouldn't pick it up). And make sure your actual strace command used `-f` from the suggestion -- leaving that out would explain the omission (as without it, child processes don't get traced).

Comment: Hm. There are other tools I might pull out at this point if debugging this myself -- [sysdig](https://github.com/draios/sysdig), [bpftrace](https://github.com/bpftrace/bpftrace) -- but I can't really fit installation and usage of those in a comment.

Comment: This got weirder, this issue only happens when my terminal is not fullscreen; the trace of the previous comment was generated in a fullscreen terminal, and when I generate it in a default size terminal there are gzip entries (along with the write syscall for the error, I should have noted its absence). I am using xfce4-terminal.

Comment: Great; if you have the syscall where the error is reported, you should be able to look back before it and find the one where the error _happened_. If we're lucky, strace will tell you right there which file the FD stdout was connected to; but even if it doesn't, it'll have all the calls showing the history of how the descriptor was assigned (through copies with `fdup()`, creations with `open()`, etc) so one can work back to figure out where stdout was connected to when the error came up.

Comment: (it's fairly likely that the descriptor was inherited from gzip's parent, in which case you'll want to look at the process that had the PID before it, and potentially the process which `fork()`ed to _create_ that process).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution to the problem but does show the reason for it. I followed @Charles Duffy 's advice and looked through the strace logs using the following command

```
strace -o man-xdotool.strace -s 2048 -ff /usr/bin/man xdotool
```

Then I searched among the files for `denied` (i.e. the process which `execve`'d gzip and gave this error), which gives me the pid where the `write` call failed. Inside there I traced back the last `dup2` call, which gave me the fd 4 (`dup2`ed and closed). I verified that this itself wasn't `dup`ed before in this process and began checking the parent process log for this fd.

In the parent process, the last `open`/`openat` call that created fd 4 before `clone` was called to spawn the child process was:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/<path-to-file>/xdotool/man/cat1/catpO12k8", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600)
```

I verified this wasn't closed before `clone`. Ahead of this I can't figure out why `gzip` isn't invoked at all when the terminal is resized, or why it is unable to write to that file.

Comment: So, what this smells like to me is your copy of `man` trying to create cat pages -- pre-rendered, preformatted versions of man pages. See `man catman`.